# Как упростить код python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Помогите упростить код телеграм бота на пайтоне. Все работает, но если добавить еще хендлеры для других дней недели и в каждом будет группа, то код получится громаднейший

```
@dp.message_handler(text='ПН')
async def send_text(message: types.Message):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT grup FROM Users WHERE id = ?', (message.from_user.id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        print('none')
    for row in result:
        if row == 'СВ-31':
            cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = 'SV_31__PN_n'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            await message.answer(row[0], reply_markup=il_1)
        elif row == 'СП-31':
            cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = 'SP_31__PN_n'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            await message.answer(row[0], reply_markup=il_1)
        elif row == 'СА-31':
            cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = 'SA_31__PN_n'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            await message.answer(row[0], reply_markup=il_1)

    connect.close()


@dp.message_handler(text='ВТ')
async def send_text(message: types.Message):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT grup FROM Users WHERE id = ?', (message.from_user.id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        print('none')
    for row in result:
        if row == 'СВ-31':
            cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = 'SV_31__VT_n'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            await message.answer(row[0], reply_markup=il_3)
        elif row == 'СП-31':
            cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = 'SP_31__VT_n'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            await message.answer(row[0], reply_markup=il_3)
        elif row == 'СА-31':
            cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = 'SA_31__VT_n'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            await message.answer(row[0], reply_markup=il_3)

    connect.close()


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='PN_p')
async def answer(call: CallbackQuery):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT grup FROM Users WHERE id = ?', (call.from_user.id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        print('none')
    for row in result:
        if row == 'СВ-31':
            cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = 'SV_31__PN_p'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            await call.message.answer(row[0], reply_markup=il_2)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='PN_n')
async def answer(call: CallbackQuery):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT grup FROM Users WHERE id = ?', (call.from_user.id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        print('none')
    for row in result:
        if row == 'СВ-31':
            cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = 'SV_31__PN_n'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            await call.message.answer(row[0], reply_markup=il_1)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='VT_p')
async def answer(call: CallbackQuery):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT grup FROM Users WHERE id = ?', (call.from_user.id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        print('none')
    for row in result:
        if row == 'СВ-31':
            cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = 'SV_31__VT_p'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            await call.message.answer(row[0], reply_markup=il_4)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='VT_n')
async def answer(call: CallbackQuery):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT grup FROM Users WHERE id = ?', (call.from_user.id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        print('none')
    for row in result:
        if row == 'СВ-31':
            cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = 'SV_31__VT_n'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            await call.message.answer(row[0], reply_markup=il_3)
```

Comment: постарайтесь сделать минимально воспроизводимый пример, код немного разбейте (например работу с бд в отдельные функции заверните)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Декоратор, это функция. Ее использование через @ — синтаксический сахар. Вы можете поступить так:

```
async def send_text(message: types.Message):
    pass

send_text_handlers = [dp.message_handler(send_text, text=wd) for wd in ('ПН', 'ВТ')]
```

Работа с группами рефакторится так:

```
groups = {'СВ-31': 'SV_31', 'СП-31': 'SP_31' }

def fetch_for_group(group_code):
    cursor.execute("SELECT `raspisanie` FROM `Schedule` WHERE `grup` = f'{group_code}__PN_n'")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row[0]

async def send_text(message: types.Message):
    ...
    for row in result:
        if row in groups.keys():
           info = fetch_for_group(groups[row])
           await message.answer(info, reply_markup=il_1)
```

Аналогично рефакторятся остальные блоки кода.